# Generating docx file from HTML file using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, sql-server-openxml

I'm using this method for generating `docx` file:

```
public static void CreateDocument(string documentFileName, string text)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentFileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();

        string docXml =
                    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                 <w:document xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">
                 <w:body><w:p><w:r><w:t>#REPLACE#</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body>
                 </w:document>";

        docXml = docXml.Replace("#REPLACE#", text);

        using (Stream stream = mainPart.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(docXml);
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm:

```
CreateDocument("test.docx", "Hello");
```

But what if I want to put HTML content instead of `Hello`? for example:

```
CreateDocument("test.docx", @"<html><head></head>
                              <body>
                                    <h1>Hello</h1>
                              </body>
                        </html>");
```

Or something like this:

```
CreateDocument("test.docx", @"Hello<BR>
                                    This is a simple text<BR>
                                    Third paragraph<BR>
                                    Sign
                        ");
```

both cases creates an invalid structure for `document.xml`. 
Any idea? How can I generate a docx file from a HTML content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot just insert the HTML content into a "document.xml", this part expects only a WordprocessingML content so you'll have to convert that HTML into WordprocessingML, [see this](http://ericwhite.com/blog/blog/htmltowmlconverter-developer-center/).

Another thing that you could use is altChunk element, with it you would be able to place a HTML file inside your DOCX file and then reference that HTML content on some specific place inside your document, [see this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/10/26/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly/).

Last as an alternative, with [GemBox.Document library](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) you could accomplish exactly what you want, see the following:

```
public static void CreateDocument(string documentFileName, string text)
{
    DocumentModel document = new DocumentModel();
    document.Content.LoadText(text, LoadOptions.HtmlDefault);
    document.Save(documentFileName);
}
```

Or you could actually straightforwardly convert a HTML content into a DOCX file:

```
public static void Convert(string documentFileName, string htmlText)
{
    HtmlLoadOptions options = LoadOptions.HtmlDefault;
    using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(options.Encoding.GetBytes(htmlText)))
        DocumentModel.Load(htmlStream, options)
                     .Save(documentFileName);
}
```

Comment: My post http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/c-net-import-xhtml-into-docx-without-word/ ends with a couple of other options

Answer (score 12):

I realize I'm 7 years late to the game here.  Still, for future people searching on how to convert from HTML to Word Doc, [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/10/26/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly/) blog posting on a Microsoft MSDN site gives most of the ingredients necessary to do this using OpenXML.  I found the post itself to be confusing, but the [source](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/09/01/75/90/altChunk.zip) code that he included clarified it all for me.

The only piece that was missing was how to build a Docx file from scratch, instead of how to merge into an existing one as his example shows.  I found that tidbit from [here](https://github.com/onizet/html2openxml/wiki).

Unfortunately the project I used this in is written in vb.net.  So I'm going to share the vb.net code first, then an automated c# conversion of it, that may or may not be accurate.

vb.net code:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Imports System.IO

Dim ms As IO.MemoryStream
Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart
Dim b As Body
Dim d As Document
Dim chunk As AlternativeFormatImportPart
Dim altChunk As AltChunk

Const altChunkID As String = "AltChunkId1"

ms = New MemoryStream()

Using myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms,WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
    mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart

    If mainPart Is Nothing Then
        mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart()

        b = New Body()
        d = New Document(b)
        d.Save(mainPart)
    End If

    chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Xhtml, altChunkID)

    Using chunkStream As Stream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Using stringStream As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(chunkStream)
            stringStream.Write("YOUR HTML HERE")
        End Using
    End Using

    altChunk = New AltChunk()
    altChunk.Id = altChunkID
    mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(Of AltChunk)(altChunk, 0)
    mainPart.Document.Save()
End Using
```

c# code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;

IO.MemoryStream ms;
MainDocumentPart mainPart;
Body b;
Document d;
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk;
AltChunk altChunk;

string altChunkID = "AltChunkId1";

ms = new MemoryStream();

using (myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    if (mainPart == null) 
    {
         mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
         b = new Body();
         d = new Document(b);
         d.Save(mainPart);
    }

    chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Xhtml, altChunkID);

    using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    {
         Using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))         
         {
              stringStream.Write("YOUR HTML HERE");
         }
    }    

    altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkID;
    mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(Of, AltChunk)[altChunk, 0];
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Note that I'm using the `ms` memory stream in another routine, which is where it's disposed of after use.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: One thing to note here is that the HTML your inserting needs to be wrapped in the `<html></html>` tag for it to be rendered as HTML, i.e. `stringStream.Write(@"<html><h2>Hi There</h2></body>")`

Comment: Conversion has removed all of the margins for me, so the output is all squished vertically. Anything to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I could successfully convert HTML content to docx file using OpenXML in an .net Core using this code

```
string html = "<strong>Hello</strong> World";
using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream()){
   using (WordprocessingDocument package = 
                  WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument,
                  WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
   MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
   if (mainPart == null){
    mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
}
HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
converter.ParseHtml(html);
mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

To save on disk

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("filename.docx", generatedDocument.ToArray());
```

To return the file for download in net core mvc, use

```
return File(generatedDocument.ToArray(), 
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
          "filename.docx");
```

Comment: What is the namespace of HtmlConverter class?

Comment: @AnandMurali It's under HtmlToOpenXml.HtmlConverter and it's part of html to openxml, visible after installing openxml nugget and dll.