# How can i create a word header from a html string

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm generating a word docx file from a html string and using various articles I've found how to add simple headers and footers to that document. 
What I now need to do is generate the header from a html string too but I'm struggling to find an example of how this is done. 
The author of this question:
[Export docx/doc First Header and Footer as docx File Using openXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46603717/2485555) 
says he has done it but unfortunately he hasn't posted an example.

My code below successfully adds a header but as you can see from the code it will only add the html as text in the header, whereas I want to pass in a html string and that to appear in the header as formatted html.

Has anyone done this?

```
static void AddHeaderPart(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string headerHtml, Encoding encoding)
        {
            if (mainPart == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerHtml))
            {return;}

            // Create a new header part.
            HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();

            // Get Id of the headerPart.
            string rId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);


            // Call GenerateHeaderPartContent
            GenerateHeaderPartContent(mainPart, headerPart, headerHtml, encoding);

            // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference with new Id.
            IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sectPrs = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();
            foreach (var sectPr in sectPrs)
            {
                // Delete existing references to headers.
                sectPr.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();

                // Create the new header reference node.
                sectPr.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = rId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
            }

        }

static void GenerateHeaderPartContent(MainDocumentPart mainPart, HeaderPart headerPart, string headerHtml, Encoding encoding)
        {
            Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

            //This adds the headerHtml as text - how to add it as html?
            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = headerHtml;

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            headerPart.Header = header1;
        }
```

Comment: you'll have to convert the html into the properly formatted word format. the ooxml sdk doesn't do that for you

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with *your* question. That one asks how to *generate* HTML from a Word document. You're asking for the opposite thing - how to *parse HTML* and generate the equivalent styling in Word. [This is a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154495/generating-docx-file-from-html-file-using-openxml). Both answers shows how to use `altChunk` to import HTML chunks into a document. There's no guarantee you'll get the same look though - HTML styles aren't Word styles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating docx file from HTML file using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154495/generating-docx-file-from-html-file-using-openxml)

Comment: thanks but that's the same article linked by P Kanavos above which I used to figure it out  - my answer is posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code below uses an altChunk to add html into the header. It's not perfect as I get validation errors when I use the OpenXmlValidator to validate the generated document although the doc still opens ok in word but I'm posting it here as an answer as it does do what I asked above & it might help others:

```
static void GenerateHeaderPartContent(MainDocumentPart mainPart, HeaderPart headerPart, string headerHtml)
        {
            Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);

            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = headerPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, altChunkId);

            // Note that headerHtml should be full html, not just a snippet
            // eg. <html><h1>My Header</h1></html> is OK
            // <h1>My Header</h1> is not OK
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding(true).GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerHtml)).ToArray());

            chunk.FeedData(ms);

            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

            Run run1 = new Run();
            RunProperties runProps = new RunProperties();
            NoProof noProof1 = new NoProof();
            runProps.Append(noProof1);

            run1.Append(runProps);
            run1.Append(altChunk);

            paragraph1.Append(run1);
            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            headerPart.Header = header1;
        }
```